# (Secondary) "Set up OneDrive" popup keeps appearing

Tags: windows-7, onedrive

Somehow I seem to have got one functioning OneDrive installation or account on my PC, and a secondary phantom one. Every time I open Windows Explorer or browse for a file, a "Set up OneDrive" window pops up and invites me to sign in to an account, even though I am already signed into an account and OneDrive is working fine on that other instance.

How do I track down the real instance and the phantom, keep the real one and kill off the phantom? I'm guessing it may have something to do with having recently subscribed to Office 365, which came with a (new) OneDrive account.

I'm running Win 7 Professional 64-bit. Under Programs & Features in Control Panel, it only lists "Microsoft OneDrive" once, and there is no SkyDrive or older variant I can see. So it seems to be a single installation expecting to connect to multiple accounts perhaps (I'm guessing...?)

The only proposed solution to similar problems has been to disable OneDrive completely. I want OneDrive to work... I just don't want it to keep telling me it isn't working when it already is.

This is the annoying popup: [image: One Drive popup]

Comment: I have the same problem. OneDrive setup itself (with my business account)  as "OneDrive - <my company>". And now there's a second "cloud icon" named "OneDrive - Personal". The second one is the one with the popup dialog. When I close the dialog, the icon disappears, too. But both reappear as soon as the business OneDrive syncs a file or I open my (business) OneDrive.

Comment: After a reinstall, the popup only appears when clicking my OneDrive folder in Explorer. At least it doesn't popup every few seconds anymore.

Comment: Screenshots would help demonstrate the issue.

Comment: I personally can't see what more a screen shot adds, but have added it. I also can't see why someone would downvote this question - this issue has persisted through all attempts at fixing it for several months now. If there is a better way of asking the question, or a better forum for it, please suggest it or edit it. Downvoting without any comment is... *facepalm*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you have a second instance under your user folder. Because I only have OneDrive for Business, it created a folder `OneDrive - <my company>` but there still was the default one `OneDrive`.

[image: Two OneDrive folders]

And every time the Explorer or some File Open/Save dialog was stumbling over that folder, the "Set up OneDrive" popup appeared.

After deleting that second folder, the popups stopped.

Comment: My popups came back with a vengeance a week or two after my uninstall/reinstall. This seems to have fixed it (fingers crossed).

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled and reinstalled OneDrive. It caused the OneDrive folder to move to a slightly different location - the original was in a subfolder (e.g. `C:\users\me\OneDrive\OneDrive - My Company`) whereas now it's not (e.g. `C:\users\me\OneDrive - My Company`). That's the only obvious difference. Whatever the case, the popup no longer pops up each time I browse.

Comment: But then it came back two months later. This is starting to get really annoying :-(

Comment: Sounds like Windows Update bringing it back. FFS MS!

Comment: Interestingly... at some point in the last week, after a flurry of restarts and Windows Updates... it mysteriously stopped all of its own accord. At least for a few days so far.